# Uniform spacing with Matplotlib and TeX

Tags: python, matplotlib, tex

I am drawing up some graphs for a math class, and I can't get the spacing for peacewise definitions quite right in the plot legend. I am currently using

```
\,
```

for a single space in TeX, but run into a situation where one is slightly farther up than other maybe due to how much the equations to the left take up. Here is my code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math as math

# 0-1
x = np.linspace(0, 1)
y = np.power(x, 2)
plt.plot(x, y, label=r"$t^2 \,\,\,\,\,\, 0 \leq t \leq 1$")

#1-2
x = [1,2]
y = [1,1]
plt.plot(x, y, label=r"$1 \,\,\,\,\,\,\, 1 < t \leq 2$")

#2-3
x = np.linspace(2, 3)
y = 3-x
plt.plot(x, y, label=r"$3 - t \,\,\,\, 2 < t \leq 3$")


plt.grid()
plt.axis([0,3,0,1.5])
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

Here is the result

[image]

How do I format this effectively in a way that will always work regardless of the pixel sizes on the left?

Comment: Do you have `usetex` turned on (a la http://matplotlib.org/users/usetex.html)?

Comment: No, I am using the r^ & $<tex>$ method.

Comment: You may have a tough time getting this to be pixel-perfect, as I don't think matplotlib's notion of legend labels is designed to support this sort of alignment of separate parts of the label.  You could try using `usetex`, which uses real TeX instead of matplotlib's approximation of it, but I don't know if that will improve things.

Comment: Would you consider using a monospaced font instead of the default serif?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can certainly improve on the spacing by accessing a lower level of LaTeX. To begin, at the top of your plots run:

```
from matplotlib import rc
rc('text', usetex=True)
```

Using a combination of [`\makebox`](http://www.personal.ceu.hu/tex/spacebox.htm#makebox) and [`\hfill`](http://www.personal.ceu.hu/tex/spacebox.htm#hfill) you can pad out the spaces between the two sections:

```
label=r"\makebox[4cm]{$t^2$ \hfill $0 \leq t \leq 1$}"
label=r"\makebox[4cm]{$1$ \hfill $1 < t \leq 2$}"
label=r"\makebox[4cm]{$3 - t$ \hfill $2 < t \leq 3$}"
```

[image]

Admittedly this isn't perfect, but with a combination of multiple `\makebox` and fills you can fine tune what you need. Ideally, you could write a custom legend handler that is "aware" of a multi-line block of TeX, but I'm sure this is non-trivial.

Comment: Hey Hooked, thanks for the great answer. I am getting deep enough into mathematics and engineering that I will soon start to have to write research papers. Do you have any good resources for learning TeX for a programmer familiar with CSS, Java and Python?

Comment: @Brandon Well there is always http://tex.stackexchange.com/ :) To help find the symbol you are looking for, there is http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html